# Quality/Distance Metric for an algorithm output

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, distance, metrics, confidence-interval

I have a machine learning algorithm which predicts a vector **(x,y,z,w,p), where x,y,z, and w are coordinates and p is the confidence with which they are predicted**.I will be the testing the algorithm on two inputs which are slightly different.So I will get two outputs v1 and v2 respectively.How do I measure the distance between v1 and v2 utilizing **p values to the optimum**?

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to take the probability into account, except for maybe adding a certainty to the distance too. You could look at the points as means and the certainty as some deviation, the distance of the means doesn't change no matter what the deviations are.

Comment: Hmm...My idea is to use an object recognition algorithm and output the bounding box and confidence for the same.So, in different weather conditions the algorithm's confidence and location of bounding box changes.Hence we need to quantify this change.

Comment: So you want your bounding boxes to become larger when there is less certainty? But I still don't see how this changes distance, this would change point locations.

Comment: I need a distance which would take into account all of this.